# Can't exec an alias or function

Tags: bash, shell, exec, zsh

I have an alias that I would like to be able to call into with `exec` but I'm not sure how to make it work. The example is simplified but I think enough to highlight the issue. Changing the alias to a function doesn't work either. Calling the alias/function directly does work, just not when using exec.

The command I am using is,

```sh
alias myalias="ls -lah /tmp"
exec myalias
```

But it fails with something similar to the following,

```sh
bash: exec: myalias: not found
```

Is it just not possible to do this using exec?

Comment: That's not an alias, that's a regular variable. You need `$` to expand variables, eg `"$myalias"`. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Why do you want to use `exec` on it? It doesn't seem to make much sense for commands like this.

Comment: In general, `exec` requires an executable file, which may or may not be provided following either alias expansion or parameter expansion.

Comment: Sorry, the original question was supposed to be using an alias. Updated with the correct snippet.

Comment: the answers (below) still apply re: how to invoke the alias; why do you keep trying to invoke it with `exec`? is this an [XP Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), ie, what's the bigger picture? what are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Right, this is a bit of a contrived example. The bigger picture is that I am using a tool that is using exec under the hood and I would like to be able save giant long commands as aliases and invoke them more easily.

Comment: @jmreicha : Why is it tagged as _bash_ **and** _zsh_? Please be explicit for which shell you are seeking a solution.

Comment: @jmreicha : Also describe exactly what effect you want to achieve. In your contrieved example, do you want the current bash process be replaced by an `ls` process?

Comment: @user1934428 tried in both shells, which is why I tagged both.

Comment: @user1934428 My end goal is to understand why I can't exec an alias, it's something I have not come across before so wanted to understand why this is happening.

Comment: To exec something means to replace the current process by a different process. Hence, you can exec only an _executable_. Neither an alias nor a function is an executable.  It's a bit if you want to drive a timetable: You can drive a bus, and you can use a timetable to find the right bus, but you can't drive a timetable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any functions or aliases in your example, but if you did have an alias, you could have aliased `exec` itself to exec it:

```
#!/bin/bash -i

# Define an alias
alias myalias="ls -lah /tmp"

# Allow `exec` to work for aliases
alias exec='exec '

# This now works as expected
exec myalias
```

Here's `man bash` for why this works:

> Aliases allow a string to be substituted for a word when it is used  as
> the  first  word  of  a  simple command. [...]
> If  the last  character  of  the  alias value is a blank, then the next command word following the alias is also checked for alias expansion.

Answer (score 0):

An alias definition:

```
$ alias myalias='ls -lah /tmp'
```

Invoking the alias:

```
$ myalias
total 36M
drwxrwxrwt+ 1 myuser None    0 Nov 30 16:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 myuser None    0 Nov  6 11:29 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser mygroup 0 Oct 10 11:31 a
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser mygroup 0 Oct 10 11:31 b
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser mygroup 0 Oct 10 11:31 c
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser mygroup 0 Oct 10 11:31 d
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser mygroup 36M Jun  6 17:29 giga.txt
drwx------+ 1 myuser mygroup 0 Mar  8  2020 runtime-makaakd/
drwx------+ 1 myuser mygroup 0 Nov  8 16:10 tmp.8yl3CJgSn2/
-rw-------  1 myuser mygroup 66 Oct 14 21:49 tmp.BeEvxDpHGr
... snip ...
```

As is (assigning string to a variable):

```
$ myalias="ls -lah /tmp"
```

'Running' the variable:

```
$ ${myalias}
total 36M
drwxrwxrwt+ 1 myuser None    0 Nov 30 16:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 myuser None    0 Nov  6 11:29 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser mygroup 0 Oct 10 11:31 a
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser mygroup 0 Oct 10 11:31 b
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser mygroup 0 Oct 10 11:31 c
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser mygroup 0 Oct 10 11:31 d
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser mygroup 36M Jun  6 17:29 giga.txt
drwx------+ 1 myuser mygroup 0 Mar  8  2020 runtime-makaakd/
drwx------+ 1 myuser mygroup 0 Nov  8 16:10 tmp.8yl3CJgSn2/
-rw-------  1 myuser mygroup 66 Oct 14 21:49 tmp.BeEvxDpHGr
... snip ...
```

Comment: My original post was incorrect, updated to use alias.